# Linux XAMPP suddenly requires 32 bit compatibility library

Tags: linux, xampp, compatibility, 32-bit, lampp

I have been working with linux's version of XAMPP (named LAMPP) for about 3 months now and up until tonight XAMPP has worked fine, but suddenly when I tried to run the command

```
sudo xampp stop
```

it gave me this error message:

```
XAMPP is currently only availably as 32 bit application. Please use a 32 bit compatibility library for your system.
```

and since then any time I try to run any of the following commands:

```
sudo xampp start
sudo xampp stop
sudo xampp restart
```

I get the same message

I want to know why I got this message because xampp has been working flawlessly up until now and in fact, less than 30 minutes ago, I typed `sudo xampp start` and xampp started up normally and I was able to access `localhost/phpmyadmin/`

Here is some other info that may be useful:

-My OS is Arch Linux

-I am using the xfce desktop environment

-In the time between starting xampp successfully and trying to stop xampp when I got the error message above, I was trying to get the php mail() function to work by following the steps on this page http://www.absolutelytech.com/2010/07/18/howto-send-emailsusing-mail-function-from-localhost-in-php-through-msmtp-using-gmail-account-on-linux/ and I had just successfully finished step 1 and successfully sent the test email to myself.

-also, when I first got the aforementioned error message, I was still able to access pages via localhost (for instance I had a php file at `/opt/lampp/htdocs/Brown/index.php` that I could access successfully by typing `localhost/Brown/index.php` even after I was getting the error message) but then I tried to restart my computer to see if that might fix the issue and now I can't start xampp to begin with.

Please someone help me with this and feel free to ask any follow-up questions if that will help

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my own issue. For anyone who sees this question, I had made a few changes to my php.ini file in attempts to get php's mail() function to work and I wanted to start fresh, so I moved `php.ini` to `php_old.ini` and copied a file named `php.ini-pre1.7.2` to `php.ini` thinking that `php.ini-pre1.7.2` was a file containing the default configuration of php.ini in case one might want to roll back to the defaults, but instead it is something entirely different. My issue was completely fixed when I moved `php_old.ini` back to `php.ini`

Answer (score 0):

2021 and the same happened to me after trying to match php.ini seetings between a Windows environment and a Ubuntu 20.04 one. Everywhere I saw it told me to comment a section in the /opt/lampp/lampp file but it messed up my installation and I lost track of what was wrong. After re-installing LAMPP I matched the settings one by one restarting with `sudo opt/lampp/lampp restart` at each modification. The culprit was:

```
browscap="C:\xampp\php\extras\browscap.ini"
```

This line has to be stay commented (just put a semicolon at the start of the line), if you need it then [this](http://linuxamination.blogspot.com/2017/12/xampp-is-currently-only-available-as-32.html) workaround may help you. Cheers!